# why my emails from my domain email id are sent to users as promotion?

Tags: google-schemas

When Users receives email from my domain specific email id he/she receives it in promotion tab.
while it should be delivered in primary email tab of inbox.How it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way emails are assigned to a specific tab depends on multiple criteria, including but not limited to the following:

1. Gmail uses a variety of signals to classify messages into the different categories.
2. Users are in control of their inboxes - they can disable some or all tabs, they can choose to move particular messages or senders into a particular category manually.
3. Gmail learns from user corrections, so over time any misclassifications, as users who receive the mail perceive them, will get automatically put into the right category.
4. It is recommended for commercial mail senders to split promotional mail from notifications/transactional mail - put those in different messages and send then from different email addresses.